# Cannot convert value of type string to expected argument type Int

Tags: json, swift

I was playing around with code. I found on GitHub (https://github.com/avijeets/ConnectFour) and was thoroughly stumped on an error I couldn't clear out.

The error is:

> "Cannot convert value of type '[[CFCellState]]' to expected argument
>   type 'Int'"

Code from the top of the VC where `CFCellState` is defined:

```
enum CFCellState: CustomStringConvertible {
    case empty
    case occupied(CFPlayer)

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .empty:
            return "empty"
        case .occupied(let player):
            return player.description
        }
    }
}
```

Code from where the error occurs:

```
self.init(player: current!, opponent: opponent!, columns:ConnectFour.boardFrom(json: queryItems[1].value!)!)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
self.init(player: current!, opponent: opponent!, board: ConnectFour.boardFrom(json: queryItems[1].value!)!)
```

In order for this to work, you may need to *remove* the `private` keyword from this line in `ConnectFour.swift` file (look around line #98):

```
private init(player: CFPlayer, opponent: CFPlayer, board: [[CFCellState]]) { ....
```

Comment: When I change to board, xcode states Incorrect argument label in call (have 'player:opponent:board:', expected 'player:opponent:columns:') and gives option to change to columns.

Comment: That did it, thanks a ton.  Now it crashes on player 2's move on that same line of code with a fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.  Fun fun.